# multiplicity of an irreducible representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Here's a quite basic question, and I'd be very glad for an answer!

The multiplicity $m_V$ of an irreducible representation $V$ in the representation $W$ of the group $G$ is given by $$ m_V = \dim \left( Hom(V,W)^G \right) $$

where $Hom(V,W)^G$ is the space of $G$-module homomorphisms from $V$ to $W$.

How to see this?

Comment: So what is the definition of multiplicity you are using? Anyway a hint: Schur's lemma.

Comment: You need $V$ to be absolutely irreducible for this to be true.

Comment: In this [document](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~fspinu/423/2.pdf) look up the notion of *intertwining operator* (2.3)  and its use in the definition of *equivalent representations*. Using Schur's lemma to see that if $W$  contains $V_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus V_n$, With $V \cong V_1 \cong \ldots \cong V_n$ then $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)^G$ has a basis of intertwining operators $T_i$ for each $V_i$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me assume that you're talking about representations of a finite group $G$ that finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$.

Since $W$ is semisimple we can decompose $W$ into irreducible direct summands as
$$ W = W_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus W_n. $$
By Schur's lemma
$$ \dim\operatorname{Hom}(V, W_i)^G = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{($V \not\cong W_i$)}
\\
1 & \text{($V \cong W_i$)}
\end{cases} $$
for each $1 \le i \le n$. Hence we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\dim \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)^G 
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^n \dim \operatorname{Hom}(V, W_i)^G
\\
&=
m_V.
\end{align*}
$$